# Recommendations for portable/fold-up work surface?

Tags: product-recommendation

Does anyone have any recommendations for portable/fold-up work benches?  Growing up, my father had a Black and Decker Workmate, but from what I've been reading construction of those work tables is different now than it was 20 years ago.  Any recommendations/experiences with anything on the market right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few variations of the Workmate, but mine is still useful at times when I need a bench away from the shop. The construction seems about the same as back when I got it. (Roughly 15 years now.)

Comment: I'm not in construction but I've used mine for well over 20 years. Although I have not looked for a replacement in a half dozen years, none match size and strength.  The others look like kid toys.

Comment: @lqlarry & woodchips - which model do you use?

Comment: Mine is a Workmate 300